# C++ template parameter that accepts a value OR a type

Tags: c++, templates, non-type-template-parameter

I'm attempting to create a simple stack using templates that accepts both values and types as the payload:

```
// type that marks end of stack
struct StackEmptyNode {};

// 
template<auto Value, typename T = StackEmptyNode>
struct StackNode {};
```

The use of `auto Value` allows me to declare stacks with values such as `StackNode<3, StackNode<4, StackNode<9>>>;`

However I also want to the same stack to accept types as the payload. This can be done by changing `auto Value` to `template Value` which allows me to declare `StackNode<int, StackNode<float, StackNode<std::string>>>;`.

I want to be able to use either for the same `StackNode` implementation. Is this possible using templates?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.  A template parameter is either a type or a value,

Comment: "_I want to be able to use either for the same StackNode implementation._": What exactly do you mean with that? On both the user side as well as in the class definition the implementation must look quite different between values and types.

Comment: Does using `template<Value, typename T = StackEmptyNode>` break the type case? If so define the stack twice, once with `auto Value` and once with `typename Value`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to use either for the same StackNode implementation. Is this possible using templates?

Short answer: no.

Long answer.
The best I can imagine is to use types and wrap values inside types, using (by example) the standard `std::integral_constant` class.

So you can write something as

```
StackNode<int, StackNode<std::integral_constant<int, 4>, StackNode<std::string>>>;
//.......................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  the value 4 become a class
```

Using the new (C++17) `auto` value facility, you can simplify a little writing a simple value wrapper

```
template<auto>
value_wrapper
{ };
```

so you can avoid the type of the value

```
StackNode<int, StackNode<value_wrapper<4>, StackNode<std::string>>>;
// ......................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  now 4 is simply 4, without it's type
```